# Dojo requesting already inlined Dijit templates --Google Closure build

Tags: dojo, template-engine, google-closure-compiler, dojo-build

I already asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17009269/dojo-build-requesting-already-inlined-dijit-templates) on StackOverflow, the [solution](https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/17141) was supposed to have been patched in commits :

- [89bf2786e322323293f52917223aa24db7649951](https://github.com/dojo/util/commit/89bf2786e322323293f52917223aa24db7649951)

and

- [783da4030bf9e727bfb4fc874b59f77521545264](https://github.com/dojo/util/commit/783da4030bf9e727bfb4fc874b59f77521545264)

But even after doing some extensive testing with this setup :

- Dojo / DojoX / Dijit 1.8.3
- Util in it's latest version (master branch on GitHub)

I keep getting the same issue.

The issue is the following :

After building my application with the util build.sh script.
My profile is :

```javascript
var profile = {
    basePath: '../src/',
    action: 'release',
    cssOptimize: 'comments',
    mini: true,
    internStrings: true,
    optimize: 'closure',
    layerOptimize: 'closure',
    stripConsole: 'none',
    selectorEngine: 'acme',
    layers: {
        'dojo/dojo': {
            include: [ 'dojo/dojo', 'dojo/i18n', 'dojo/domReady', 'app/main', 'app/run', 'app/widgets/Application'],
            boot: true,
            customBase: true
        },
    },
    staticHasFeatures: {
        'dojo-trace-api': 0,
        'dojo-log-api': 0,
        'dojo-publish-privates': 0,
        'dojo-sync-loader': 0,
        'dojo-xhr-factory': 0,
        'dojo-test-sniff': 0
    }
};
```

and running :

```sh
java -Xms256m -Xmx256m  -cp ../shrinksafe/js.jar:../closureCompiler/compiler.jar:../shrinksafe/shrinksafe.jar org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main  ../../dojo/dojo.js baseUrl=../../dojo load=build --require "$myConfig" --profile "$myProfile" --releaseDir "$myReleaseDir" $@
```

- 1) My Dijit templates are inlined in the output file like they should, but when running the app, Dojo is still making Ajax requests for the already inlined templated !
- 2*) The nls directory is placed in the wrong directory (dojo directory in place of the root directory) and has to be moved. (I'm not sure if this is related to the bug I encounter.)

Inline format is :

```
"url:path/to/my/template.html":'<p>Some escaped HTML</p>'
```

Template require format :

```
dojo/text!./path/to/my/template.html
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

I also had similar problem. In my application i used multiple dijit widgets and to avoid many AJAX calls I created a layer.

```
layers:{
'dijit/mydijit':{
    include:["dijit/_base","many dijit widgets"]
}
```

After including `dijit/mydijit.js` in my application the browser kept on making AJAX call for `dijit/_base`

To solve this problem i added `dijit/_base` as dependency of `dijit/mydijit` layer

```
layers:{
'dijit/mydijit':{
    include:["dijit/_base","many dijit widgets"],
    dependecies:["dijit/_base"]
}
```

After this there are no requests for `dijit/_base.`

Hope this helps you :)